# Delete all git docker images in the gitlab registry except images tagged as latest

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am rewriting my gitlab CI/CD pipeline and I would be including a stage, which would tag the latest image as latest, so I would like to delete every other image in the registry. I was looking at the API, however, I did not find anything appropriate that would let my ci-runner delete all the images, which have a tag different than `latest`.